"Missing Relationship Cache Data" won't go away
Got this "Missing Relationship Cache Data" each time, even after cache rebuilt in Web GUI / API4.
Could it be because some relationships in the database don't have a start_date but have an end_date?



If you visit the status page of Civi(CiviCRM >> Administer >> Administration Console >> System Status), you should see the option to rebuild the relationship cache table.
The count of civicrm_relationship_cache table should be twice of civicrm_relationship. If the count is not matching than it means a record is either having missing contact id a or b.

yes I did a few times from both WEB GUI and by running a corresponded CV command in a terminal, but the message is still back each time I log in.
